# Tag synonym request: certificates -> certificate

Tags: discussion, status-completed, synonym-request

Title says it all :)

[certificates](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/certificates) should become a synonym for [certificate](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/certificate)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've merged and synonymized the opposite direction, since plurals tend to work better as tags, at least to my mind.  A question tagged [certificates](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/certificates) is "on the subject of" certificates or "regarding" certificates.  Anyways ... :P